# How to override a CSS class

Tags: css

I have a webpage that is generated by Drupal and it comes with a certain stylesheet attached to it.

I would like to override one of the styles. It is set with a class like this:

```
<div class="description"></div>
```

So instead of using the ".description" style that comes with the Drupal CSS, I would like the page to use my ".description" style. In other words - if the page has 2 ".description" styles, how do I tell the page to use mine?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Use a selector with [higher specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/):

   ```
   div.description {
       /* will take precedence over just .description */
   }
   ```
2. Place your stylesheet after the one you want to override:

   ```
   /* Drupal's style */
   .description {
       foo: bar;
   }

   /* Your style */
   .description {
       foo: baz; /* takes precedence over foo: bar */
   }
   ```
3. **Do not use `!important`.** Just don't.

See also [CSS 3: Calculating Selector Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

Comment: when I look at the source code of the generated page, my stylesheet is the last one declared, and yet my .description style is not the one being used. any ideas?

Comment: Nope. Do you have a link? If not, use Firebug or Chrome/Safari dev tools to dig through the applied styles.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what's so bad about using `!important`? **Edit**: [Nevermind, I'll see myself out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css).