# Why does a combination of code works but not a single instance to override Bootstrap Jumbotron H2 style?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a little confused about the specificity here...

```
.container-fluid, .row, .col-md-12, .jumbotron, h2 {
background-color: blue;
}

.container-fluid.row.col-md-12.jumbotron, h2 {
background-color: blue;
}
```

Works, but either of these sets of code individually don't work...

HTML is:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>
                Hello, world!
            </h2>
```

What is the correct way to override bootstrap CDN(or bootstrap.min)with my local CSS file?

My files are linked like this:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom CSS override your class with higher specificity
Take a look at this answer . Creadit @Matt Ball   [Override a css Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323995/how-to-override-a-css-class)